# Problems with javascript function onchange

Tags: javascript, php

Hello stackoverflow people, i've been coding for sometime and got stuck with this script. Because i cant find out why im getting console error:

> ```
> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
>
>
> var Nlang = document.getElementById('langSelect').value;
> ```

ive tried doing as function onchange and ve tried this:

```
document.getElementById('langSelect').onchange = function() {
```

But that didnt worked too. What is wrong with this script, here is my javascript code:

```
function WasChanged(){
    var Nlang = document.getElementById('langSelect').value;
    var currentUser = <?php echo json_encode($AppUI->user_id); ?>;
};
```

And here is my php code:

```
    echo arraySelect($langlist, 'pref_name[LOCALE]', 'onchange="WasChanged()" class="text" size="1"', $userLang, true);
```

[image]

Comment: Add the HTML source too.

Comment: `echo arraySelect($langlist, 'pref_name[LOCALE]', 'onchange="WasChanged()" class="text" size="1"', $userLang, true);` This is the code witch creates the html with select

Comment: It is not the html source. It is the script that generates the html.

Comment: where is this id `langSelect` in your html?

Comment: I updated, in the picture there is the code

Comment: @McLaren just add an id to your `select` like this `<select class="text" id="langSelect"......`

Comment: SORRY MY MISTAKE, AFTER WEEKEND XDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `document.getElementById('langSelect')` returns null, there must not be a div with that ID in the Dom.